# Android Intent to launch appropriate chat client

Tags: android, android-intent, chat

In my application, I'd like to provide a Chat button. In the context of a specific contact, the user is shown a list of the contact methods available. For example, it might list a Google Talk ID and an AIM ID. The user can click on either ID and it should launch the appropriate application that handles the selected chat protocol (if one is installed). Given that I have the protocol and the ID (e.g., PROTOCOL_GOOGLE_TALK and "JohnDoeGtalk"), how can I create an intent that does that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding @gmail.com in your URI?

The following approach, taken from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5687aed2f49b1789?pli=1), works for me; it opens a new chat with the contact, using the Google Talk app. Using HTC Desire running Froyo. Code:

```
Uri imUri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("imto").authority("gtalk").appendPath("example@gmail.com").build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, imUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This works for me. I tried it on a Razr running 2.3.x and a Xoom tablet running ICS. In the append path section you can put who you want to chat with. I was able to open a chat session with someone on an internal server using the IP address of the server ( i.e. "name@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx").  I was using Xabber for the xmpp client.

Answer (score 0):

An `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent` with a `Uri` whose scheme is `imto://...` may work. See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=981) and comment #2 for the apparently-valid syntax. Note that I have not tried this, and this issue is from quite some time ago.

Comment: Thanks! This works, in that it does open the Google Talk application. However, it does not start a new chat session. Here is the code I am using: newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("imto://gtalk/johndoegtalk"); Is there something I have to add (perhaps with setExtra?) to make it open a new chat?

Comment: @Tom: If that doesn't open up a chat session, I suspect that there is no `Intent` to do it.